# I ran out of CO2

Tags: beer

After replacing the empty CO2 tank with a new/full CO2 tank, my beer is still flat. After 48 hours, it flows from the kegerator, but is as flat as could be. Is the keg ruined?

Comment: A little more info might help. For example: what pressure is your CO2 regulator set to; do you hear any hissing that might indicate a leak; what carbonating method are you using; what temperature is it?

Answer (score 1):

The keg should be fine. Oxygen shouldn't have gotten in, unless it was a corny keg with really bad seals. Carbonation time for a standing keg is something like a week (or more?), but I would expect some carbonation after two days. If crank up the pressure up to 20 or 30psi and shake the keg for half an hour, you can get it done much quicker.

If you don't hear CO2 going through the regulator while shaking the keg, then something is wrong mechanically. Also, if there are CO2 leaks you'll find them quickly this way.

Comment: Do NOT shake the keg for half an hour: Start with a minute or two, and then test by pouring some been after reducing the pressure in the keg to serving pressure. Shaking for 30 minutes at 20-30psi will surely overcarbonate the beer to the point where you will get nothing but foam.

Comment: The time required to carbonate by shaking depends on temperature of the beer and the surface area available in the keg. It could happen quicker, but that a minute or two certainly isn't enough. The thing to do is shut of the CO2 periodically, shale some more, and see where the pressure ends up. (of course your using a chart to find the target pressure, right?)

Comment: I have over-carbonated cold beer in less than 5 minutes.